# Keystone.js Not able to upload same file again

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I am uploading the same name file again but it is showing 'Field Error '. I have checked the log it is due to unique File name error . But I do not want to change the name of the file . Anyone having any solution for that. I am using keystone framework

Comment: Which type of file are you trying to use (LocalFile, S3, Cloudinary), and what version of Keystone are you running?

Comment: I am using latest version of keystone and try to upload LocalFile.

Comment: Can you post the entirety of the error? I can't seem to research if file overwriting is expected behavior or not, or if an option will change that.

Comment: I have found alternative solution and added random no before file name Date.now(). Thanks