# Is it possible in keystone to upload same file again?

Tags: css, file-upload, keystonejs

I could see solution at this link [Keystone.js Not able to upload same file again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974929)  but adding timestamp won't work for me as I am uploading css in keystone(**local fileupload**) and using it in html, so I can't rename css again and again as timestamp changes . So do anyone have idea if this is possible in keystone?Am I on right direction in uploading .html and .css throgh keystone CMS?

I am using originalname in order to avoid auto generated file names after uploading.

Comment: Is `originalname` an option of `{ type: Types.LocalFile }`? I cannot find such an option on [the documentation](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fieldtypes-localfile "LocalFile").

Comment: I found it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821564/keystone-js-local-file-uploads-being-auto-renamed it's not there in documentation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524442/keystone-js-s3-image-uploads-being-auto-renamed-with-temporary-string/31573836#31573836. Also type: Types.LocalFile is now Types.File.